# Is there any way to load poster after html5 video ended

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I was wondering if any event can be called after an HTML video have been played.

Comment: Self-answers are ok, but you should write a correct question to which you will answer. As it stands now, your question is only in the title, which is not good.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("video").bind("ended", function() {
    this.load();
    $('video').prop("autoplay", false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add- video.addEventListener('ended',function() {});